# `setCalculateVarImportance` changes result in `cv2.ml.RTrees` model

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, opencv

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html) for `cv2.ml.RTrees`, it says

> calcVarImportance – If true then variable importance will be calculated and then it can be retrieved by RTrees::getVarImportance.

It sounds like this parameter should only change whether the variable importance is calculated or not. It should not change the model's output.

However, as the MCVE below shows, it does. Why?

```
import cv2
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data
y = data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1729)

forest = cv2.ml.RTrees_create()
forest.setTermCriteria((cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,10,1))
forest.setCalculateVarImportance(True)
forest.train(cv2.ml.TrainData_create(np.float32(X_train), 0, y_train))
preds = forest.predict(np.float32(X_test), 0)[1]
print(sum(preds))
# output: [94.]

forest = cv2.ml.RTrees_create()
forest.setTermCriteria((cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,10,1))
forest.setCalculateVarImportance(False)
forest.train(cv2.ml.TrainData_create(np.float32(X_train), 0, y_train))
preds_new = forest.predict(np.float32(X_test), 0)[1]
print(sum(preds_new))
# output: [95.]
```

Comment: What does `sum(preds)` suppose to represent? What exactly are the numbers 94 & 95?

Comment: @desertnaut the elements of `preds` can be either `0` or `1` (according to which class the model predicts), so `sum(preds)` is the total number of test samples which the model predicts to be in class 1. The only reason I had to print it is to have a compact way of showing that the model's predictions have changed.

Comment: Nice catch (+1); I thought that it might be due to the inherent randomness in RF, but it turns out that even repeating the calculations many times, this difference (94 vs 95) is always there. Seems to me like a bug, I kindly suggest you open an issue at their [GIthub repo](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python).